# Cannot change default text editor using update-alternatives

Tags: linux, configuration, editors, defaults, alternatives

I want to use vim over nano as default text editor. I tried to do it with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

From menu I chose vim. However, when I open any file, Linux launches nano just as before. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: How did you try to open the file? Could you add the output of `update-alternatives --display editor` to your question? What happens when you run the `editor` command?

Comment: Did you relogin?

Comment: @sborsky I open the file in Midnight Commander

Comment: @bodqhrohro Yes, I did relogin

Comment: @EmKa Midnight Commander has it's own settings for opening files in some programs. Go to `Command` -> `Edit extension file` to change it. By the way, the extension file itself should open in the editor you have already configured system-wide.